# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se ejecute todo o nada en múltiples peticiones en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable, angular13

Estoy realizando 2 peticiones

- Operaciones CRUD sobre un objeto
- Registro de esas operaciones que se realizaron

Investigando para tratar de manejar las peticiones, investigando encontre  el operador **Forkjoin** el cual lo hice para realizar las 2 peticiones en paralelo y poder manipular el resultado si era exitoso

El problema que tengo es de que si falla la primer petición no hay problema no se continua con las demás pero si la primer petición es exitosa y la segunda no el objeto sufre la mutación que causa la primera

Como podría evitar este error para que todas las peticiones se cumplan o de no completarse al menos una ya sea la primera o la segunda no seguir

services.ts peticion 1

```
  eliminar(id: string): Observable<IResponse> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/empleados/${id}`
    return this.http.delete<IResponse>(url).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.warn(
          'Error',
          error
        );
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    )
  }
```

services.ts peticion 2

```
guardarRegistro(usuario: string, accion: string): Observable<IRegistroResponse> {
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/registro`
let data = {usuario,accion}
return this.http.post<IRegistroResponse>(url, data).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.warn(
        'Error',
        error
      );
      return throwError(() => error);
    })
  )
```

}

component.ts

```
eliminarE(empleado: Empleado): void {
    let accion = `Elimino empleado ID:${empleado.id_empleado}`
    const eliminar = forkJoin({
      eliminar: this.empleadoService.eliminar('prueba'),
      registrar: this.bitacoraService.guardarRegistro(this.usuario.usuario, accion)
    });
  eliminar.subscribe(({eliminar,registrar}) => {
           console.log("Resultado 1" + JSON.stringify(eliminar))
           console.log("Resultado 2" + JSON.stringify(registrar))
          }
        });
```

Comment: Y por qué es el front quien se encarga de loguear las acciones? Debería ser tu backend quien mantenga el log de acciones realizadas, y de paso te evitarías este problema :)

Comment: si yo se que toda esa lógica debe de ser por el backend pero así me lo asignaron y pues no queda mas que hacerlo...

Comment: Pues es que el problema con hacerlo desde front es el siguiente: un observable de http no da error hasta que falla... y si no falla, es que ya se ha hecho y no puedes revertirlo. Quiero decir, si la primera llamada va bien y la segunda falla... no hay nada que puedas hacer más que reintentar el que ha fallado, pero no puedes cancelar una llamada http terminada OK, porque ya está terminada. No se pueden hacer las llamadas http como si fuesen una transacción en la DB, una vez se ha ejecutado una, se queda ejecutada. Tu servidor ha realizado los cambios, no hay más

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por el aporte intentare que se haga mejor todo eso en el back